# enviar datos POST devbridge jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Amigos, tengo este código usando la herramienta `devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete`
el cual me permite escribir unas ciudades y el nombre de un usuario, pero como logro enviarlo a través de un botón enviar?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My World</title>
    <link href="content/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<form action="datos.php" method="POST">

    <div class="container">Usurio<input type="text"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <p>Escriba su ciudad:</p>
        <div style="position: relative; height: 80px;">
            <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-ajax" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; background: transparent;"/>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="autocomplete-ajax-x" disabled="disabled" style="color: #CCC; position: absolute; background: transparent; z-index: 1;"/>
        </div>
        <div id="selction-ajax"></div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mockjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="countries.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

al enviar el form, trato de obtener los datos con el siguiente codigo

```
<?php 
    echo "ciudad : " .$_POST('country');    
?>
```

pero no logro obtener resultados, como puedo enviar esa información y recuperarla?
de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Salvo que haya cambiado en las nuevas versiones de PHP no es `$_POST('country')` si no `$_POST['country']`

Comment: perdón lo escribi manualmente aquí, pero si está como dices con el corchete, pero ni así, de hecho si imprimo un var_dump
echo "ciudad : " .var_dump($_POST);

aparece esto: array(1) { ["country"]=> string(6) "Russia" } 
es decir los datos si se envían, solo no se como obtenerlos, sacarlos del array y que array es